# Number format in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set my array to 0 decimal place. I know that it has to be some `number.format=0`. But I do not know where to place it. And sorry for the format of my code, it is not in gray because I do not know to use it.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Function arraydemo(r As Range)
    Dim cell As Range, i As Integer, x(40, 1) As Double

    i = 1

    For Each cell In r        
        x(i, 1) = Rnd * 40
        i = i + 1
    Next cell

    arraydemo = x
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is in Double, so when you store random result to array, it will in decimal automatically, you can delete the decimal with change declaration of array from decimal to integer, but this will delete decimal value from random result.
I think the best way is: modify the decimal from the  result of your function.
Example :

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range
Dim A As Variant

Set r = Range("A1:A40")

A = arraydemo(r)

For i = 1 To UBound(A)
    Range("A1").Offset(i) = A(i, 1)
    Range("A1").Offset(i).NumberFormat = "0"
Next

End Sub
```